# How to find out what caused PTE exhaustion?

Tags: windbg, bsod

I have my Windows 10 bluescreen several times and I have memory dump and running `!vm` produces output below showing 0 available PTEs. How do I find out postmortem who leaked those or monitor on live system which process/driver responsible for leak?

```
0: kd> !vm
Page File: \??\C:\pagefile.sys
  Current:   9961472 Kb  Free Space:   9961464 Kb
  Minimum:   9961472 Kb  Maximum:     62351824 Kb
Page File: \??\C:\swapfile.sys
  Current:     16384 Kb  Free Space:     16376 Kb
  Minimum:     16384 Kb  Maximum:     49881460 Kb
No Name for Paging File
  Current: 129378408 Kb  Free Space: 129362880 Kb
  Minimum: 129378408 Kb  Maximum:    129378408 Kb

Physical Memory:         16756646 (   67026584 Kb)
Available Pages:         11876350 (   47505400 Kb)
ResAvail Pages:          15917045 (   63668180 Kb)
Locked IO Pages:                0 (          0 Kb)
Free System PTEs:               0 (          0 Kb)

********** Running out of system PTEs **************

Modified Pages:            249289 (     997156 Kb)
Modified PF Pages:         249261 (     997044 Kb)
Modified No Write Pages:       25 (        100 Kb)
NonPagedPool Usage:          3042 (      12168 Kb)
NonPagedPoolNx Usage:      103383 (     413532 Kb)
NonPagedPool Max:      4294967296 (17179869184 Kb)
PagedPool  0:              144048 (     576192 Kb)
PagedPool  1:               31595 (     126380 Kb)
PagedPool  2:               31923 (     127692 Kb)
PagedPool  3:               31631 (     126524 Kb)
PagedPool  4:               31714 (     126856 Kb)
PagedPool Usage:           270911 (    1083644 Kb)
PagedPool Maximum:     4294967296 (17179869184 Kb)
Processor Commit:            1348 (       5392 Kb)
Session Commit:             17782 (      71128 Kb)
Shared Commit:             658461 (    2633844 Kb)
Special Pool:                   0 (          0 Kb)
Kernel Stacks:              26919 (     107676 Kb)
Pages For MDLs:            395401 (    1581604 Kb)
Pages For AWE:                  0 (          0 Kb)
NonPagedPool Commit:        97838 (     391352 Kb)
PagedPool Commit:          270911 (    1083644 Kb)
Driver Commit:              19721 (      78884 Kb)
Boot Commit:                 2732 (      10928 Kb)
PFN Array Commit:          196913 (     787652 Kb)
System PageTables:           3267 (      13068 Kb)
ProcessLockedFilePages:       306 (       1224 Kb)
Pagefile Hash Pages:            0 (          0 Kb)
Sum System Commit:        1691599 (    6766396 Kb)
Total Private:            4330147 (   17320588 Kb)
Misc/Transient Commit:       9281 (      37124 Kb)
Committed pages:          6031027 (   24124108 Kb)
Commit limit:            19247014 (   76988056 Kb)

  Pid ImageName                        Commit   SharedCommit        Debt

 598c vmmem                        3677256 Kb           0 Kb        0 Kb
  4d4 RemoteDesktopManager.exe     1367276 Kb      473008 Kb        0 Kb
 6300 vmmem                        1050684 Kb           0 Kb        0 Kb
 207c vmmem                        1050684 Kb           0 Kb        0 Kb
 1d18 vmmem                        1050684 Kb           0 Kb        0 Kb
 276c powershell.exe                713052 Kb        4660 Kb        0 Kb
 483c chrome.exe                    635112 Kb      130192 Kb        0 Kb
 3ad4 chrome.exe                    525988 Kb       20672 Kb        0 Kb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Russinovich, Mark; Solomon, David; Ionescu, Alex. Windows Internals, Part 2 (6th Edition) (Developer Reference)

> you can enable system PTE tracking by creating a new DWORD value in
>   the HKLM\ SYSTEM\ CurrentControlSet\ Control\ Session Manager\ Memory
>   Management key called TrackPtes and setting its value to 1. You can
>   then use !sysptes 4 to show a list of allocators

So you could try to

- set the registry key and reboot
- use `livekd`on the running system and execute `!sysptes 4` to get al list of allocators
- or execute `!sysptes 4` on a dump you collect

Comment: @Gregory-Suvalian - did you manage to find the culprit? Would you care to share what it was?

Comment: I did not yet, just this is enough for me to start working. Once I know I will update the thread